# Can't really find what is the error in this code

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Trying to do an ordering system using java for some school project but had an error while compiling.

I badly need your help guys. please ;-;

this is the error:
[Picture error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBMrk.jpg)

I have the following source code here:

```
public class fastfood {
public static void main(String[] args){
  int quantity,total,price1,price2;
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("\t\t   Welcome to fastfood restaurant!\t\t");
  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println("\t\t\t\tMENU\t\t\t\t");
  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println("   Order code\t\t Meal\t\t\t\t Price ");
  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println("      (A1)   \t\t Burger\t\t\t\t P30");
  System.out.println("      (A2)   \t\t Spaghetti\t\t\t P80");
  System.out.println("      (B1)   \t\t Peach mango pie\t\t P40");
  System.out.println("      (B2)   \t\t Chicken meal\t\t\t P100");
  System.out.println("      (C1)   \t\t Hotdog sandwich\t\t P30");
  System.out.println("      (C2)   \t\t Fries\t\t\t\t P20");
  System.out.println("      (D1)   \t\t Ice cream\t\t\t P25");
  System.out.println("      (D2)   \t\t Water\t\t\t\t P15");
  System.out.println(" ");
  System.out.println(" ");

  do{
  System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
  String name = reader.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Enter your order(Code): ");
  String order = reader.nextLine();
  if(order("A1")){
      price1 = 30;
      System.out.println("Order description: Burger");
  }
  else if(order("A2")){
      price1 = 80;
      System.out.println("Order description: Spaghetti");
  }

  System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
  quantity1 = reader.nextLine();

  total += price1 * quantity1;

  System.out.println("Another Order?  (Y/N) : ");
            again = reader.nextLine();
            if (again("y")){
             }   loop1=loop1+1;
  } while (loop1==1);   

}
}
}
```

Comment: Hint : indent your code properly

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the last `if` statement

```
if (again("y")) {
    loop1=loop1+1;
}
```

So the compiler considered the bracket from the ´do...while´ as the closing bracket of your `if` statement

I'd suggest you to indent your code properly next time. The answer jumps right in front of your eyes when you do it.

If you're working on Eclipse, select all the code (Ctrl + A) and then press `CTRL + I`. Eclipse will take care of the indentation

Comment: actually i closed that. got an error while pasting my code. sorry.